# Query custom node by user Entity Reference

Tags: database

I am trying to build a query that finds all nodes of a custom type where one of the fields is a user Entity Reference.  I am trying to use EntityFieldQuery but just as open to db_select().  The following is just an example of one of the queries I have tried.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node', '=')
  ->propertyCondition('type', 'custom_node', '=')
  ->fieldCondition('field_marketer', 'value', $user->uid, '=');

$entities = $query->execute();
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Wouldn't that be 'field_user_entity_reference'?

Comment: The actual field name is 'field_marketer'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The column name for an entity reference field is `target_id`, so your code should be:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node', '=')
  ->propertyCondition('type', 'custom_node', '=')
  ->fieldCondition('field_marketer', 'target_id', $user->uid, '=');

$entities = $query->execute();
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you again Clive! This was my first attempt at using EntityFieldQuery.